# Pass selected value in dropdownlist from view to controller when form post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have these models and a view model. When form posting to create the entries, the selected value for `WardID` and  `DoctorID` becomes zero in the controllers POST method.

View code

```
@model NewClient.HospitalMgt.ViewModel.PatientAdmissionViewModel
.... 
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Admission.WardID, "Ward")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("WardID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Admission.WardID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Admission.DoctorID, "Doctor")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("DoctorID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Admission.DoctorID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Patient.PatientName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Patient.PatientName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Patient.PatientName)
        </div>
        .... //more controls for properties of Patient

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Admission.AdmissionNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Admission.AdmissionNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Admission.AdmissionNumber)
        </div>
        .... //more controls for properties of Admission
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Controller code

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.WardID = new SelectList(db.Wards, "WardID", "WardNumber");
    ViewBag.DoctorID = new SelectList(db.Doctors, "DoctorID", "DoctorName");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PatientAdmissionViewModel Id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var c = new Patient()
        {
            Address = Id.Patient.Address,
            ContactNumber = Id.Patient.ContactNumber,
            EmergencyContact = Id.Patient.EmergencyContact,
            PatientName = Id.Patient.PatientName,
        };
        var a = new Admission()
        {
            AdmissionNumber = Id.Admission.AdmissionNumber,
            AdmissionDate = Id.Admission.AdmissionDate,
            **WardID = Id.Admission.WardID, //becomes zero 
            DoctorID = Id.Admission.DoctorID //becomes zero** 
        };
        db.Patients.Add(c);
        db.Admissions.Add(a);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.WardID = new SelectList(db.Wards, "WardID", "WardNumber", Id.Admission.WardID);
    ViewBag.DoctorID = new SelectList(db.Doctors, "DoctorID", "DoctorName", Id.Admission.DoctorID);
    return View(Id);
}
```

Models and View models

```
//[NotMapped]
public class PatientAdmissionViewModel 
{
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public Admission Admission { get; set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Patient Name is required")]
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Contact Number is required")]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyContact { get; set; }
    public virtual Ward Ward { get; set; }
}

public class Admission
{
    public int AdmissionID { get; set; }
    public string AdmissionNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PatientID { get; set; }
    public int WardID { get; set; }
    public int DoctorID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime AdmissionDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Ward Ward { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PatientPayment> PatientPayments { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use of `@Html.DropDownList("WardID", String.Empty)` and `@Html.DropDownList("DoctorID", String.Empty)` are generating inputs with `name="WardID"` and `name="DoctorID"` respectively, but you model does not contain properties with those names (it does however contain a property named `Admission` which contains those properties).

You 'view model' is not really a view model (a view model should not contain properties which are data models when editing). Your view model should also contain properties for the `SelectList`'s so that you can strongly bind to your model. Your view model needs to be

```
public class PatientAdmissionViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Ward"]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a ward")]
    public int? SelectedWard { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Doctor"]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a doctor")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> WardList { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedDoctor { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DoctorList { get; set; }

    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    ... // other properties of Patient that you need in the view

    public string AdmissionNumber{ get; set; }
    ... // other properties of Admission that you need in the view
}
```

and in the GET method, initialize an instance of the view model, set its properties and return it to the view

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new PatientAdmissionViewModel()
    {
        WardList = new SelectList(db.Wards, "WardID", "WardNumber"),
        DoctorList = new SelectList(db.Doctors, "DoctorID")
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedWard, Model.WardList, "-Please select-")
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDoctor, Model.DoctorList, "-Please select-")
```

and finally, in the POST method, you initialize new instances of your data models, set their properties based on the values in the view models and save the data models.

I also recommend you read the answers to [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc).

Comment: You attempted to make an edit to my answer. That edit was wrong and I rejected it. If your getting an error when you POST, then refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
@Html.DropDownList("WardID", String.Empty)
@Html.DropDownList("DoctorID", String.Empty)
```

use this on view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Admission.WardID, (SelectList)ViewBag.WardID, "--Select One--")
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Admission.DoctorID, (SelectList)ViewBag.DoctorID, "--Select One--")
```

use this on controller

```
 WardID = Id.Admission.WardID, 
 DoctorID = Id.Admission.DoctorID
```

Comment: will try this one too, big help from the experts makes fun to code

Comment: The validations and the order of the properties must be matched other wise **The ViewData item that has the key '' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>** error comes `        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> WardList { get; set; }
         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a ward")]
        public int? SelectedWard { get; set; }
   
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DoctorList { get; set; }
         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a doctor")]
        public int? SelectedDoctor { get; set; }`